# in julia 1.0, what new syntax? error: { } vector syntax is discontinued

Tags: function, vector, syntax-error, julia, declare

i'm using julia 1.0 and have a error,
`syntax: { } vector syntax is discontinued`
with this code below:

```
function abc{Ti<:Integer,Tf<:FloatingPoint}(Ns::Ti,rho::Array{Tf,1},
            M::Array{Ti,1};Niter::Ti=5,rate::Tf=.5,Mc::Ti=2,mSparse::Ti=0,
            strategy::Ti=2,Nmat=1)
```

i searched for function and method julia syntax but don't have any idea. Please help me solve this error, thanks.
Update:

I still tried to convert it to 1.0 and detected that the source code causing {} vector syntax error is discontinued. It is below:

pColor = {"r>-", "bo--","kx-.","gd-", "c^--","m*-.","rs--","gp-.","bv-", "kh--","c+-.","m.-",};

Can you help me fix it in new syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where` operator instead like this:

```
function abc(Ns::Ti,rho::Array{Tf,1},
            M::Array{Ti,1};Niter::Ti=5,rate::Tf=.5,Mc::Ti=2,mSparse::Ti=0,
            strategy::Ti=2,Nmat=1) where {Ti<:Integer,Tf<:FloatingPoint}
```

assuming you have a `FloatingPoint` type defined (in Base an equivalent would be `Real` or `AbstractFloat` depending on what you exactly want to accept).

Here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods-1 is a relevant section of the Julia manual explaining how to define parametric methods.

Comment: I still get same error when use where operator instead like you share

Comment: i tried changing FloatingPoint to Real (base), Float16(core) but it still did not work :(

Comment: Saying just that it doesn't work isn't very helpful. What inputs are you using? What, precisely, is the error message? Can you provide code that we can copy and run, to see what the problem is?

Comment: Very sorry for the lack of information provided, i try to run a a sample source, you can download here: https://github.com/christianpeel/LDPCsim.jl
An error occurred in line 663. Many thanks

Comment: This code is developed under Julia 3.6 which you can check in REQUIRE file. I recommend you to use that version of Julia to run it. Porting it to Julia 1.0 will require a significant effort as it is incompatible in numerous places.

Comment: sry that i'm brand new with julia but i think latest version julia is 1.0.1, why you say it is developed under julia 3.6?
Pkg.status() show below:
[c52e3926] Atom v0.7.7
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.14.0
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.12.0
  [e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.5.3
   [b964fa9f] LaTeXStrings v1.0.3
  [429524aa] Optim v0.17.1
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v0.20.4
  [438e738f] PyCall v1.18.4
  [d330b81b] PyPlot v2.6.3
  [60ddc479] StatPlots v0.8.1

Comment: hi, i understand what you say, julia 0.3.6 :). do you think about downgrade version :(

Comment: Correct Julia 0.3.6. Sorry for a typo. If you want to port the code to Julia 1.0 there is a lot of work to be done not just changing one line. Here http://bogumilkaminski.pl/projects/ I maintain a brief introduction to Julia since version 0.3 so you can compare the guide to see the most important differences.

Comment: I understand. I tried to comment some code, debug it and more element like cell function, integer type, tic function, round function with array, .. error (underfine, not match, ..).
Maybe I should try julia from scratch, and move on to version 0.3.6 for this source code. Many thanks, Bogumil.